# frameworks to support RIA/Web 2.0 technologies

Tags: ria, web-frameworks

are there any frameworks that can help an application support all/most of the RIA technologies like ajax, flex, javafx, siverlight?

essentially a framework and/or tools to help build an application that can support client-side UI components built using RIA technologies.

How does GWT fair in this respect?

Answer (score 0):

Not good = GWT. 
Use a javascript library like Dojo, ext js or YUI.
For simpler things jquery would suffice.